# Custom elements works for Safari but not for Firefox and Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, web-component, custom-element

I'm sure I'm missing something fundamental from the spec, but after building a large set of custom elements on the Mac running on Safari, I find they don't work on Firefox and Chrome. What am I missing?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>NoCE</title>
        <script>
            class NoCE extends HTMLElement {
                constructor(args) {
                    super();
                }

                connectedCallback() {
                    this.innerHTML = "<p>It Works</p>";
                }

                attributeChangedCallback(name, oldValue, newValue, namespaceURI) {}

                disconnectedCallback() {}

                adoptedCallback() {}

                static get observedAttributes() { return []; }
            }

            customElements.define("no-ce", NoCE, { extends: "div" });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <no-ce>
            No custom elements
        </no-ce>
    </body>
</html>
```

In Safari the page shows "It Works". In Firefox and Chrome it shows "No Custom Elements" (running on Mac OS X.)

Safari 12.0.2
Firefox 64.0.2
Chrome 71.0.3578.98

Comment: I see removing { extends: "div" } helps but then I lose div inheritance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You mixed up definitions of **autonomous custom element** (aka new HTML tag) with **customized buit-in element** (aka standard HTML element extension) which have a slightly different syntax.

For **Autonomous Custom Element**:

```
class NoCE extends HTMLElement
...
customElements.define( 'no-ce', NoCE )
...
<no-ce><no-ce>
```

For **Customized Built-in `<div>` Element**:

```
class NoCE extends HTMLDivElement
...
customElements.define( 'no-ce', NoCE, { extends: 'div'} )
...
<div is='no-ce'></div>
```

Safari doesn't implement customized buit-it elements, and therefore will ignore the `extends` option and process your code as a simple autonomous custom element.

On the other hand, Chrome and Firefox will ignore your custom element definition because it is not correct.

---

If you want to make your custom element inherit from `<div>` you should first extend the `NoCE` class with `HTMLDivElement`, and then use the `<div is="no-ce">` syntax. (But that won't work in Safari without a polyfill.)

Alternately, if you want to create your own HTML tag with a basic `<div>` behavior, you could define an autonomous custom element and apply to it the `{display:block}` CSS style.

```js
class ACE extends HTMLElement {
  connectedCallback() {
    this.attachShadow( { mode: 'open' } )
        .innerHTML = `<style> :host { display: block } </style>
                      Autonomous CE works`
  }
}
customElements.define( 'a-ce', ACE )


class CBE extends HTMLDivElement {
  connectedCallback() {
    this.attachShadow( { mode: 'open' } )
        .innerHTML = `Customized DIV works`
  }
}
customElements.define("c-ce", CBE, { extends: "div" } )
```

```html
<a-ce>autonomous custom element not implemented</a-ce>

<div is="c-ce">customized built-in element not implemented</div>
```