# customElements not working in google chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, custom-element

I'm trying to use some custom elements in my website, and in firefox it works great so far. In google chrome however, it just fails silently - the constructor of my custom element is never called, and it also doesn't throw an error.

Suppose this minimal example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            class MyElement extends HTMLDivElement {
                constructor(){
                    super();
                    this.style.background = "#00ff00";
                    console.log("Created custom element!");
                }
            }
            function addCustomElement(){
                customElements.define("my-element",MyElement,{extends:"div"});
                console.log("Added MyElement to custom element registry!");
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="addCustomElement()">
        <my-element style="display:block;width:100px;height:100px;background:#ff0000"></my-element>
    </body>
</html>
```

I would expect this to create a custom element class `MyElement` and convert all `my-element`-elements in the DOM into instances of that class once added to the custom element registry, turning the originally red component green. In firefox, this is exactly what happens, but in google chrome, it stays red. The console indicates that the element was added to the registry, but its constructor was never called.

Am I missing something? Is this a problem with chrome, or am I doing something wrong? And how can I get it to work there?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Custom elements works for Safari but not for Firefox and Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54160445/custom-elements-works-for-safari-but-not-for-firefox-and-chrome)

Comment: @Supersharp I'm not so sure about that, it deals with the same underlying topic but quite a different issue. Edit: nevermind, I guess that comment was automatically sent when you suggested that question. oops.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Working example here

```
class MyElement extends HTMLElement  {
   constructor(){
   super();
   this.style.background = "#00ff00";
   console.log("Created custom element!");
   }
}
function addCustomElement(){
   customElements.define("my-element",  MyElement)  
   console.log("Added MyElement to custom element registry!");
}
// add call here, because onload did not work for me
addCustomElement()
```

https://jsfiddle.net/so98Lauz/1/

changes:

- extend HTMLElement instead of HTMLDivElement
- call `addCustomElement` function in js to be sure that is executed
- removed `{extends:"div"}` from `customElements.define`

Comment: Yup, changing `HTMLDivElement` to `HTMLElement` and removing the `,{extends:"div"}` indeed fixed this for me. Thanks. Also, I just noticed that on the [mdn compatibility table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomElementRegistry/define#Browser_compatibility) it says chrome supports "autonomous custom elements only" - I guess that's why extending `HTMLDivElement` didn't work.

Comment: Any idea why it doesn't works with `{extends:"div"}` and `HTMLDivElement` option? As per [developers.google.com](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-components/customelements#extendhtml) this syntax is also supported

Comment: Unforunately i have no idea, I just tried to get it to work and checked against [google developer customelements docs](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-components/customelements) 

accoriding to mozilla it should work 
[mozilla CustomElementRegistry/define docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomElementRegistry/define)

but chrome showed me an error, when extending something else than ` HTMLElement`

Comment: I know this is old, but nobody addressed the reason why the original code with `extends` didn't work. The reason is, when you use `extends`, that component  needs to be defined on the HTML then use `is` to mention the web component extension. In this case it was supposed to use `<div is="my-element"></div>`. As it's described at [extending-native-html](https://web.dev/custom-elements-v1/#extending-native-html-elements)

Answer (score 8):

I just checked [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements) again and found this:

> There are two types of custom elements:
>
> 1. Autonomous custom elements are standalone — they don't inherit from standard HTML elements. You use these on a page by literally writing them out as an HTML element. For example `<popup-info>`, or `document.createElement("popup-info")`.
> 2. Customized built-in elements inherit from basic HTML elements. To create one of these, you have to specify which element they extend (as implied in the examples above), and they are used by writing out the basic element but specifying the name of the custom element in the is attribute (or property). For example `<p is="word-count">`, or `document.createElement("p", { is: "word-count" })`.

This means that since `MyElement` extends `HTMLDivElement`, the correct syntax would be `<div is="my-element">`, and not `<my-element>`. Firefox seems to accept `<my-element>` nonetheless, but chrome doesn't.

Using the correct syntax, this seems to work on both browsers:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            class MyElement extends HTMLDivElement {
                constructor(){
                    super();
                    this.style.background = "#00ff00";
                    console.log("Created custom element!");
                }
            }
            function addCustomElement(){
                customElements.define("my-element",MyElement,{extends:"div"});
                console.log("Added MyElement to custom element registry!");
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="addCustomElement()">
        <div is="my-element" style="display:block;width:100px;height:100px;background:#ff0000"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

There's also a note on [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomElementRegistry/define#Browser_compatibility) stating that chrome supports autonomous elements only; this doesn't seem to be true however, since the snippet above seems to work just fine.

Comment: (1) No need for ``addCustomElement`` function, elements can be defined before the load event (or long after). (2)Customized Builtin Elements (=extended) are not (yet) supported in Opera and Safari, there is a [Polyfill](https://github.com/ungap/custom-elements-builtin) (3)When you create a element with ``document.createElement`` the ``is`` attribute is **not** set on the element.. if you need it (eg. for CSS selectors) you have to do a ``.setAttribute("is","my-element")`` in your ``connectedCallback``; (4) note! you can **not** change an element into something else with the ``is`` attribute

Comment: For pros/cons of extending the IMG element see: https://cardmeister.github.io